# some php functions not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on ticket system (Osticket) , I install my environment by using XAMPP (PHP 7.2.7) latest version and I finish the project, all things work fine.

When I test my code on manual installed php, mysql the ticket system  works fine and part of new added code works fine.

What's not working is mysqli:

```
query: "INSERT INTO scan_files(file_name , sha256 , result ,  ticket_number , 
topic , topic_id) VALUES ('$file_name' , '$hash_of_file' , '1' 
,'$get_ticket_id' , '$topicNum' , '$topicID')"
```

also fopen function is not working:

```
file_put_contents('/srv/http/ost/scan/apires.txt', 
print_r($api_reply_array['positives'], true));

$myfile = fopen("/srv/http/ost/scan/newfile.txt", "w") ;
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = $hash_of_file . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = $api_reply_array['positives'] . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = $file_name . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

I give permission to folder and give permission to my code.
I think there is some modules needed.

all things working fine with xampp environment ,but i get problem with manual installation of php and mysql.

php version is 7.2.8

mysql version is Server version: 10.1.34-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: Can you add the mysqli PHP usage to the actual question?

Comment: Also, what error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the exact problem with the given description is very tough.

However, you can add the following lines to top of your PHP code to enable error reporting, to identify the exact issue.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

> PS : To enable parse errors also, edit php.ini file and add
>   `display_errors = on`

Comment: Thanks for you answer , i already enable display error , but there is no error :( , it's just skip my function

Answer (score -1):

### Problem 1

With your MySQL issue, it could be that perhaps the columns do not match the actual SQL schema, or the table does not exist, or one or more of your PHP variables do not have a value, but your schema is set up to disallow empty field values.

That being said, I would highly recommend that you use **prepared statements** when interacting with a database.

### Problem 2

With the `fopen issue`, it could be a file permissions problem or the path does not exist. i.e. `file_put_contents` will not create the directory structure for you.

Comment: I'd assume the double quotes on the SQL are for the encapsulation in the PHP.. and if SO the update you've made will cause a fatal PHP error.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't originally notice the double quotes around the SQL statement. I'll update my answer.